# Pig Latin In Python Conversion

Tags: python

```
def convert_pig_latin(pig):
    first_letter = pig[0]
    #Check if Vowel
    if first_letter in 'aeiou':
        pig_word = pig + 'ay'
    else:
        pig_word = pig[1:] + first_letter + 'ay'   
        print('Pig Latin:',pig_word)
```

So basically, this only works for 1 single word input. Let's say the user enters a sentence, it won't work which is obvious. This code is in my functions tab, and my main module of course runs it with an input sentence given. Could someone please help me out how it'll take a whole sentence instead of just one word -.- Tried using a for loop but messed it up.

Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension here:

```
def pig_latin(sentence):
  return ' '.join([s + 'ay' if s[0] in 'aeiou' else s[1:] + s[0] + 'ay' for s in sentence.split()])

print(pig_latin("convert all the words"))
```

Output:

```
onvertcay allay hetay ordsway
```

You could also keep your current approach where the function converts a single word, and use `map()`:

```
>>> def pig_latin_word(s):
...   return s + 'ay' if s[0] in 'aeiou' else s[1:] + s[0] + 'ay'
...
>>> ' '.join(map(pig_latin_word, "convert all the words".split()))
'onvertcay allay hetay ordsway'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've learned off of it and realized my mistake. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the string into a list of strings:

```
words = pig.split(' ')
```

Then you would run a for loop on the list:

```
for word in words:
    #run your conversation code on each word
```

Then join the list back into a string:

```
pig = ' '.join(words)
```

Comment: Thank You for your response! Really Appreciate it! Forgot about lists comprehensions and .split()